# Undefined reference to 'function name'

Tags: c, linker-errors, header-files

I am a CS student currently trying to learn C. I just started creating my own header files and as a fun little project I wanted to create a library of my own that can handle big integers in a string based way. There are simply three files; bignumbers.h, bignumbers.c, test.c .

bignumbers.h:

```
#ifndef BIGNUMBERS_H
#define BIGNUMBERS_H

//Typedef Declaration
typedef struct big_number{
    char digit;
    struct big_number *next_digit;
} *BIGNUMBER;


//Function Declaration
int number_length(char number[]);
BIGNUMBER create_digit(char digit);
BIGNUMBER create_number(char number[]);
//Macro Declaration

#endif // BIGNUMBERS
```

bignumbers.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Actual functions
#include "bignumbers.h"
int number_length(char number[]){
    /*code to get string length*/
}

BIGNUMBER create_digit(char digit_){
    BIGNUMBER number_digit;
    number_digit = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUMBER));

    if(number_digit == NULL){
        printf("Memory allocation failed!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    number_digit->digit = digit_;
}

BIGNUMBER create_number(char number[]){
}
```

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bignumbers.h"

int main(){
    number_length("1");
}
```

Trying to compile test.c gives me an error with the message "undefined reference to 'number_length'
error: ld returned 1 exit status"

There is no typo in test.c as far as I'm aware. So what might be the problem here? I understand that "ld returned 1 exit status" is a linker problem but I don't really see what can cause that.

Comment: Please describe how you are building the files. That is, what is the command line or project set up?

Comment: I'm using codeblocks' build and run option.

Comment: `sizeof(number)/sizeof(char)`. OT: But note that that is not going to work. In C, arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function. So `sizeof(number)` is always the same value - the size of a single pointer. The size of array params cannot be calculated inside a function and must be passed in.

Comment: Also, `create_digit` needs to return something

Comment: I wanted an easy way out for getting the string length without using string.h but it seems I failed. Thanks for pointing that out!
I will add a return statement after solving this problem.

Comment: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -O2 -o name_of_exe test.c bignumbers.c` You must compile both `test.c` and `bignumbers.c` concurrently. Otherwise, compile `bignumbers.c` to an object file using the `-c` option and then link the object with your compile of `test.c` (above `"name_of_exe"` can be whatever you want your executable named, presumably `test` in this case). Also, don't accept code until it compiles without warning. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow` enable a good set of warnings to help you. If you are using VS, then use `/W3` to enable warnings.

Comment: `number_digit = malloc(sizeof(BIGNUMBER));` You need to allocate enough space for a `struct big_number` but instead you only allocate space for a pointer.  This kind of thing is why it's a bad idea to `typedef` a pointer type.

Comment: I don't know codeblocks, but I believe @DavidC.Rankin has the answer you're looking for. Everything compiles OK, but the two source files aren't linking. `test.c` understands that `number_length` exists somewhere (the header says so) but isn't being told where to find the actual code. You either need to compile both C files separately then link them (`gcc -c bignumbers.c && gcc -c test.c && gcc bignumbers.o test.o`) or compile and link them both together in the same command (`gcc bignumbers.c test.c`).